# Button and Input Keep Overlapping Each Other

Tags: html, css, styling, overlap

> Ok so I'm trying to program a bar that appears at the top of the webpage. On that bar I want there to be a title, a button, and an input/search bar. My problem is that the input keeps overlapping the button in the top bar. Please note that the bar at the top is a div. Here is the link to the page with the bug: [Link to the page](https://langmesh.beware4.repl.co/).

This is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Langmesh</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="topbardiv">
      <h1 id="titletext">Langmesh</h1>
      <button onclick="browse()" id="browsebutton">Browse</button>
      <input type="text" id="searchbar" value="Search">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS code:

```
#titletext {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: "Brush Script MT", sans-serif;
}

#topbardiv {
  background-color: darkorange;
  text-align: center;
  border: 10px solid lightgray;
}

#topbardiv h1,
#topbardiv button {
  margin: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1.5px #000000;
}

#browsebutton,
#searchbar {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: "Brush Script MT", sans-serif;
  background-color: darkorange;
  border: 0;
}
```

I have not added any Javascript yet.

If this is a stupid question with a simple answer and I'm just dumb, feel free to criticize me.

I tried using text a button and an input in the same div and used css to put them all right next to eachother and I expected that it would look like a bar at the top with a title a browse button and a search bar but instead the search bar and the browse button ended up overlapping.

I am using a Windows 10 OS and replit to program the page and a chrome web browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because you have set the width of the `#browsebutton` and `#searchbar` elements. Please unset it and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'roboto';
}
.container {
text-align: center;
}
.container input {
border: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px;
  height: 33px;
}
.container button {
border: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px;
  height: 33px;
}
.container h1 {

}
.background_css {
  width: 100%;
  background: orange;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Langmesh</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="background_css">
    <h1 id="titletext">Langmesh</h1>
 
<form method="POST" action="page.html" class="search_css">
  <input type="search" placeholder="Search..."><button type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This should work for you, remember you need to check your html using an HTML syntax checker. If you want the search button to be on the left, then put the button tag before the input, but always make sure to keep the input and button on the same line. <3